# NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2

I am getting this warning in Eclipse:

> NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB in:
>         org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.validation.internal.facelet.messages ICEfacesPage1.xhtml /myapp/src/main/webapp

On the following lines:

```
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
```

Any ideas why, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This is an Eclipse quirk. Try one of the following things:

- Close/reopen project.
- Rightclick project > *Validate*.
- *Project > Clean...* and clean selected project.
- Restart Eclipse.

Comment: The above is the sort of generic advice that I give to new users. Closing the project worked for me, but not validating. Eclipse is bad mojo.

Comment: For me, none worked, I don't know if it's related, but I'm using Debian.

Answer (score 4):

This was also the case when I imported a JSP taglib, for example:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt">
</html>
```

I closed the project and reopened, and it worked!

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is an old post but I hope this may help somebody.
I recently installed the ICEfaces plugin (IF-3.3.0-IM-1.3.0-Eclipse-4.3-plugins-B.zip) for Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler).

I created a New ICEface Facelets Composition Page using the page creation wizard.

[image]

After creating the page, I got the same warning message.

[image]

I checked the the index.xhtml that was generated out of the box when I created my ICEfaces application and there's a discrepancy.

[image]

Changing my new page ns from www.icesoft.org to www.icefaces.org made the warning disappear.

[image]