# Eclipse + JSF + Facelets + composite component = CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf-2, facelets, composite-component

I'm trying to add a composite component to my JSF Facelets application.

The composite component (email.xhtml) is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
    <title>This content will not be displayed</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="value" required="false" />
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
        <h:outputLabel value="Email id: "></h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}"></h:inputText>
    </composite:implementation>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The using page (emailuserpage.xhtml) is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:em="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/emcomp/">

<h:head>
    <title>Using a sample composite component</title>
</h:head>

<body>
    <h:form>
        <em:email value="my@email.address" />
    </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

The path to my composite component is `src/main/webapp/resources/emcomp/email.xhtml`.
The path to my user page is `src/main/webapp/emailuserpage.xhtml`.

**But I get both compile time and run time warnings in emailuserpage.xhtml, and nothing (besides a warning message) gets displayed in the browser**

Compile time warning shown in Eclipse JSF HTML editor:

```
xmlns:em="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/emcomp/"
NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB in: 
 org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.validation.internal.facelet.messages
```

Run time warning shown in Eclipse browser (javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE=Development in web.xml):

```
Warning: The page /emailuserpage.xhtml declares namespace http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/emcomp/ and uses the tag em:email , but no TagLibrary associated to namespace.
```

I've already seen this question (it didn't solve the problem): [NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7546219/987687)

I'm using the `m2e` and `m2e-wtp` plug-ins, with Eclipse version:

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers
Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857
```

**Any ideas on what I'm doing incorrectly?
Have I included the composite component incorrectly somehow, or am I using the wrong directories to store my resources?
Is this an Eclipse/configuration problem?**

**[EDIT]**

In response to Daniel's comment

SOURCE directory structure:

- project/src/main/

  - java/
  - webapp/

DEPLOY directory structure:

- project

  - HTML files
  - resources/ (including emcomp/ folder)
  - META-INF/
  - WEB-INF/ (config files and lib/ folder)

Comment: Are you sure that the path shouldn't be: webapp/resources/ instead of src/main/webapp/resources/ ?

Comment: @Daniel, I'm using the default Maven directory structure. See edited question for further details.

Comment: just curios replace <body> with <h:body> , this stuff can mess the JSF ...

Comment: thanks for the tip, but it didn't help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the trailing slash from the XML namespace URI.

```
xmlns:em="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/emcomp"
```

Comment: I have the same problem but have no trailing slash :(