# JBoss 7.1, JSF, RichFaces - rich components don't want to render

Tags: jsf, jboss, richfaces

I'm learing RichFaces now for my JSF project, but i have problem with rendering rich components in my enviroment.

I have added RichFaces jar(all 4 jars from RichFaces page) to JBoss modules (E:\JBoss\modules\org\richfaces\main) with module.xml:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.richfaces">
<resources>
<resource-root path="richfaces-components-api-4.2.1.Final.jar"/>
<resource-root path="richfaces-components-ui-4.2.1.Final.jar"/>
<resource-root path="richfaces-core-api-4.2.1.Final.jar"/>
<resource-root path="richfaces-core-impl-4.2.1.Final.jar"/>
<!-- Insert resources here -->
</resources>
<dependencies>
<module name="org.w3c.css.sac"/>
<module name="net.sourceforge.cssparser"/>
<module name="com.sun.jsf-impl"/>
<module name="javax.api"/>
<module name="javax.faces.api"/>
<module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
<module name="javax.xml.jaxp-provider"/>
<module name="com.google.guava"/>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

All dependencies were added to jboss modules by default configuration.

I created simple JSF page with RichFaces from tutorial:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">

<h:head></h:head>
<body>
    <rich:panel>
        <f:facet name="header">
        Write your own custom rich components with built-in AJAX support
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="Panel Body" />
    </rich:panel>
    <rich:panel>
        <f:facet name="header">
        Write your own custom rich components with built-in AJAX support
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="Panel Body" />
        <a4j:form>
            <h:outputText value="The integer version of the selected color:" />
            <h:outputText id="RGBvalue" value="#{colorPickerBean.color}" />
            <rich:panel header="RichFaces Color Picker" style="width: 315px">
                <rich:colorPicker value="#{colorPickerBean.color}" colorMode="rgb"
                    converter="org.richfaces.IntegerColor">
                    <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="RGBvalue" />
                </rich:colorPicker>
            </rich:panel>
        </a4j:form>
    </rich:panel>

</body>
</html>
```

Both xmlns in head tag are highlighted with "NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB in: org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.validation.internal.facelet.messages"

I've deployed my new xhtml page for JBoss and now rich components aren't handled proper. Next listing shows source of deployed page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich" xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"><head></head>
<body>
    <rich:panel>Panel Body
    </rich:panel>
    <rich:panel>Panel Body
        <a4j:form>The integer version of the selected color:<span id="RGBvalue"></span>
            <rich:panel header="RichFaces Color Picker" style="width: 315px">
                <rich:colorPicker colorMode="rgb" converter="org.richfaces.IntegerColor">
                    <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="RGBvalue"></a4j:support>
                </rich:colorPicker>
            </rich:panel>
        </a4j:form>
    </rich:panel>

</body>
</html>
```

My jboss-deployment-structure.xml in WebContent/META-INF:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <sub-deployment name="Tutorial2.war">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.richfaces" slot="main">
                <imports>
                    <include path="**" />
                </imports>
            </module>
        </dependencies>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Modules defines as showed in link https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-12008

After few more changes I got

```
00:29:52,455 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."Tutorial2.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Tutorial2.war".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "Tutorial2.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: Sub deployment Tutorial2.war in jboss-structure.xml was not found. Available sub deployments: 
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.subDeploymentNotFound(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:233) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.deploy(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
```

Error occurs as soon as I add jboss-deployment-structure.xml to WEB-INF.

Comment: Is your `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` in Tutorial2.war? If it is, then it probably shouldn't be a `<sub-deployment/>`. Have a look at the documentation.  https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7#ClassLoadinginAS7-JBossDeploymentStructureFile

Comment: I have tried without subdeployment section and tag rich tags don't want to render.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
   <deployment>
      <dependencies>
        <module name="org.richfaces" slot="main" />
      </dependencies>
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's probably an issue with eclipse. It seems there are a few different questions along the same lines with eclipse and JSF. Most of them seem to say something [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7546248/152794) one does.

Comment: Thanks, problem with Eclipse warnings solved, but pages still don't want to render proper.

Comment: I attached source file before deploying and view source after deploying. All tags rendered proper, only rich and a4j didn't render.

Comment: Are you adding an org.richfaces dependency to your deployment? Maybe in your MANIFEST.MF or using a jboss-deployment-structure.xml.

Comment: I rechecked jboss-deployment-structure.xml and attached it to question.

Comment: Your slot is wrong. Should be `<module name="org.richfaces" slot="main">` or just leave the slot attribute off, main is the default.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, the same problem exists after changich 4.2.1 to main.

Answer (score 0):

see following discussion on jboss forum
https://community.jboss.org/message/633025#633025
and search for the correnct answer

you should supply jboss7 specific deployment descriptor jboss_deployment_structure.xml to make richfaces module available to your application

Comment: I rechecked jboss-deployment-structure.xml and attached it to question.