# why won't RichFaces 4 components render properly?

Tags: spring, jsf, jboss, richfaces

I'm using RichFaces 4 along with JSF, Spring, and Spring Web Flow on JBoss EAP 6.1, migrating from corresponding technologies on JBoss EAP 5.1 (e.g., RichFaces 3.3).

The problem is that any component or control in the rich: namespace will have some HTML generated for it, but when it is rendered in the browser, it looks nothing like the corresponding component on the RichFaces showcase site. It seems as though there are CSS and maybe image files that should be bundled with the RichFaces jar files, but the browser is not able to find them. Screen shot below.
[image: screen shot 1].

As a test, I chose a simple control, the rich:collapsiblePanel and pasted the sample code from the showcase website into a test page in our application. The collapsible panel appears, but looks nothing like the one on the demo site. Screen shot below.
[image: screen shot 2].

I'm getting the same result across multiple browsers (IE, Firefox, and Chrome) and across multiple rich: components (rich:extendedDataTable, rich:tabPanel, rich:calendar for example) so I think this points to a library or configuration issue.

Below is a list of libraries I'm using.

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar
aspectjweaver.jar
cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
commons-codec-1.5.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-digester-2.1.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar
cssparser-0.9.5.jar
guava-r09.jar
jdom.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
org.springframework.binding-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.faces-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.js-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.js.resources-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.webflow-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar
poi-3.8-20120326.jar
richfaces-components-api-4.3.2.Final-redhat-1.jar
richfaces-components-ui-4.3.2.Final-redhat-1.jar
richfaces-core-api-4.3.2.Final-redhat-1.jar
richfaces-core-impl-4.3.2.Final-redhat-1.jar
sac-1.3.jar
spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-tomcat-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-acl-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-aspects-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-cas-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-crypto-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-ldap-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-openid-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-remoting-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-taglibs-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-struts-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-test-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
```

And here's my web.xml, with only a few parts changed for anonymity (app-servlet.xml and com.app.class).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/app-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
    <param-value>DEFAULT</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>1</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <filter>
        <filter-name>RewriteRequestHeaderFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.app.class</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>RewriteRequestHeaderFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping> 

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

I've also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758434/richfaces4-dont-render-the-components) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311045/jboss-7-1-jsf-richfaces-rich-components-dont-want-to-render) which seem to be related, but I couldn't find any information to help solve my problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a SSCCE web page?

Comment: it doesn't load clearly the css of richfaces, what about right click in chrome and inspect elements to see if css are loaded and reachable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was a Spring configuration issue. If you're using Spring and/or Spring Web Flow, check for the following code in your config files. Note that these are just code snippets, not complete config files.

webflow-config.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.3.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces-2.2.xsd">
```

webmvc-config.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces-2.2.xsd">

    <faces:resources />

    <!-- Needed for RichFaces! -->
    <bean name="richfacesResourceHandler" class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfResourceRequestHandler" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="order" value="0" />
        <property name="mappings">
            <value>
                  /rfRes/**=richfacesResourceHandler
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: disclaimer: my co-worker figured this out. i just posted it in case someone else ran into the same problem.