# How to disable warning "NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB"

Tags: eclipse, jsf, namespaces, facelets, jboss-tools

I'm getting this annoying warning 
`NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB in: org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.validation.internal.facelet.messages` within a facelet page because the composite components namespace could not be validated. I think this is a JBoss Tools validation problem because the composite components library isn't located within the same Eclipse project.

I've found several validation entries under 
`Preferences > JBoss Tools > Web > JSF > Validation`,
`Preferences > JBoss Tools > Web > Knowledge Base > Validator` and 
`Preferences > Web > JavaServer Faces Tools > Validation` but could not find the right option to ignore the "NLS missing message".

Where could this warning message be disabled? Thanks for advice!

Comment: possible duplicate of [NLS missing message: CANNOT\_FIND\_FACELET\_TAGLIB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546219/nls-missing-message-cannot-find-facelet-taglib)