# xmlns:jsf=“http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf” is unknown

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, xhtml

I'm trying to make a custom tag in jsf, here is my code: WEB-INF/tag/test.xhtml

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
    xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite">

    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="value" type="java.lang.String" default="#000000" />
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
        <div id="#{cc.clientId}">
            <input jsf:id="#{cc.id}" name="#{cc.id}" jsf:value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
                type="color" />
        </div>
    </cc:implementation>
</html>
```

the problem is that eclipse doesn't recognize xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf" it give me a warning says:

```
 NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB in: org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.validation.internal.facelet.messages
```

so what is the problem. Note: all the other Namespaces work fine unless this one

Comment: May be you can try this solution in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546219/nls-missing-message-cannot-find-facelet-taglib

Comment: I already try that but nothing change